# How to make alias compatible with links?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I am trying to make a bash script that recognizes specific links from a text file, then sends a command that replaces a specific string in a different file with a image link.
This is what I have right now.

```
#!/bin/bash
alias https://www.examplelink.com='sed -i -e "/replacen_next_line/s/\".*\"/\"https://www.exampleimage.com\"/" to/image/replace.txt';
cd /to/link/file/example;
. ./filewithlink.txt;
```

I get this message whenever executed

```
./filewithlink.txt: https://www.examplelink.com: not found
```

The script works fine without links. So I assume special characters is the reason it isn't working. Not sure if this is necessary information but these are all the special characters used in the links :/._-?=

Comment: please update the question with more details on what you mean by *`isn't working`* ... error messages? wrong results? no results? something else? right off the bat ... `sed` default script delimiter is `/`, but you also have `/` in your data so `sed` will have problems when it sees 'extra' delimiters; a couple options come to mind ... a) escape the `/` that show up as data or b) use a different delimiter (preferably something you know won't show up in the data, eg, `~`, `|`)

Comment: You should probably be using a shell function, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Deep in the dungeons of the `bash` manuals, there is the remark:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

Because you source the script, you might create a function instead of an alias.

Or, if that is not to your liking,

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```